# Detail in proof of $\sup\limits_tM_n(t)\overset{P}{\to}0\iff[M_n]_{\infty}\overset{P}\to 0.$

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, martingales

I was reading a proof in Kallenberg's book *foundations of modern probability* but there are two things I don't understand.

**Notation :** For continuous local martingales $M,N$, the quantity $[M,N]$ denotes the covariation process and we denote $[M]:=[M,M]$.

> **Proposition 18.5** For any continuous local martingales $M_n$ starting at $0$, we have
> $$\sup\limits_tM_n(t)\overset{P}{\to}0\iff[M_n]_{\infty}\overset{P}\to
> 0.$$
>
> *proof :* First let $\sup\limits_{t}M_n\overset{P}{\to}0$. Fix any $\epsilon>0$, and define $\tau_n=\{t\ge
> 0;|M_n|>\epsilon\},n\in\mathbb{N}$. Write $N_n=M_n^2-[M_n]$, and note
> that $N_n^{\tau_n}$ is a true martingale on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}_+$.
> In particular $E[M_n]_{\tau_n}\le \epsilon^2$, and so by Chebyshev's inequality $$P\{[M_n]_{\infty}>\epsilon\}\le P\{\tau_n<\infty\}+\epsilon^{-1}E[M_n]_{\tau_n}\le P\{\sup\limits_t M_n>\epsilon\}+\epsilon.$$ [...]

The first thing I don't understand is how we can say $E[M_n]_{\tau_n}\le \epsilon^2$.

The second thing that is not clear to me is in the step

> $P\{[M_n]_{\infty}>\epsilon\}\le
> P\{\tau_n<\infty\}+\epsilon^{-1}E[M_n]_{\tau_n}$

It seems that there is an intermediate step $P\{[M_n]_{\infty}>\epsilon\}\le P\{\tau_n<\infty\}+P\{[M_n]_{\tau_n}>\epsilon\}$ which I don't understand (and then we apply Markov on the right hand side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $M^{\tau_n}_n$ is bounded, $N^{\tau_n}_n$ is a uniformly integrable martingale, hence by Doob's stopping theorem,
$$
E N_{\tau_n}=0,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
E[M_n]_{\tau_n}=E\vert(M_n)_{\tau_n}^2\vert\le E\varepsilon^2=\varepsilon^2.
$$

For the second thing,
$$
P\{[M_n]_\infty>\varepsilon\}=P\{[M_n]_\infty>\varepsilon,\tau_n<\infty\}+P\{[M_n]_\infty>\varepsilon,\tau_n=\infty\}.
$$

On the one hand,
$$
P\{[M_n]_\infty>\varepsilon,\tau_n<\infty\}\le P\{\tau_n<\infty\}.
$$

On the second hand, using Markov's inequality for the last inequality,
$$
P\{[M_n]_\infty>\varepsilon,\tau_n=\infty\}=P\{[M_n]_{\tau_n}>\varepsilon,\tau_n=\infty\}\le P\{[M_n]_{\tau_n}>\varepsilon\}\le\frac{E[M_n]_{\tau_n}}{\varepsilon}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In the computations $E[M_n]_{\tau_n}=E\vert M_{\tau_n}^2\vert\le E\varepsilon^2=\varepsilon^2$ is it actually $E[M_n]_{\tau_n}=E\vert (M_n^2)_{\tau_n}\vert\le E\varepsilon^2=\varepsilon^2$. Also, the inequality is just for the case $\tau_n=\infty$ right? Otherwise we would have $(M_n)_{\tau_n}=\epsilon$?

Comment: Yes I mixed up the notations, sorry for that. I edited the answer. And yes, we have $(M_n)_{\tau_n}=\varepsilon$ on the set $\{\tau_n<\infty\}$, or equivalently, $1_{\{\tau_n<\infty\}}(M_n)_{\tau_n}=1_{\{\tau_n<\infty\}}\varepsilon$. The case $\tau_n=\infty$ is a bit tricky since $(M_n)_{\infty}$ does not really make sense. One should understand by $(M_n)_{\tau_n}$ the almost sure limit of $M_n^{\tau_n}$, which exists as it is a bounded martingale.